# Возможно ли сделать на yii2 отдельный модуль для RestFull

Tags: yii2

Вобщем нужно сделать модуль на yii2 который будет работать как RestFull. Вот часть конфигурации

```
     'urlManager'=>[

        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/books','v1/authors']],
        ],

    ],
```

Но при такой конфигурации не работает простая маршрутизация на всем сайте

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример моего рабочего конфига:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'site/index',

            'GET v0/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>.<_format>' => 'v0/<controller>/view',
            'GET v0/<controller:\w+>.<_format>' => 'v0/<controller>/index',

            'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<id:[\w\d\-]+>.<_format>' => 'v1/<controller>/view',
            'v1/<controller:[\w\-]+>.<_format>' => 'v1/<controller>/index',
        ],
    ],
```